# How to install libasound2-dev 32 bit without using apt-get?

Tags: python, gcc, arm, shared-libraries, microprocessors

I'm working on a module with microprocessor arm A7 (32 bit) that use a Debian based distro and I'm trying to use pyaudio library. Launching the script I get the following error:

```
libportaudio.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

"sudo apt-get portaudio19" don't find the package for several reasons , so I downloaded the source code by the official web page and compiled it on hand.

Running:

```
./configure
```

I obtain at the end:

```
Target....................armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
C++ bindings..............no
Debug output..............no

ALSA......................no
```

etc.
libasound2 is installed but not libasound2-dev and, again,

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
```

don't find the package.
So, I'm searching for the source code but I found only 64bit version or not suitable version for my microprocessor.

Anyone know where can I find the source code of the package for a generic version 32bit?

Thanks!

Comment: What about `sudo apt-get portaudio2`? `sudo apt-get libportaudio2`? Are you sure that the file `libportaudio.so.2` is not installed by any of the debian packages? Did you try to search them?

Comment: None of these commands work. Unfortunately it is a very castrated version of OS

Comment: Are you building *on* your target machine?

Comment: Yes.Anyway I downloaded libasound2-dev_1.1.6-1ubuntu1_armhf.deb and when I tryied to install with apt-get I saw the following error: Dependes: libasound2 (= 1.1.6-1ubuntu1) but 1.1.6-r0 is to be installed, but I'm not finding any 1.1.6-r0 version of "dev"

Comment: @Asoftware, did you ever find a solution for this? I have a similar issue, where "libasound2-dev depends on libasound2 (=1.1.3-5) but 1.1.3-5+rpi3 is to be installed". It seems that its dependency has a slightly different version number, and it refuses to recognize it as a valid dependency version.